# RedirectToPage() not working in ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following code in LogOut razor page.

```
public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
  await loginManager.SignOutAsync();
  RedirectToPage("/Identity/Login");
}
```

But it is not redirecting to login page as expected. It still shows LogOut page.

If I use Response.Redirect() instead of RedirectToPage() then it works.

I am using Preview 3 of ASP.NET Core 3.

Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `RedirectToPage()` method is *generating* a `RedirectToPageResult` that you forgot to actually `return` from your action.

Try this instead:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    await loginManager.SignOutAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("/Identity/Login");
}
```

Comment: No other way wihtout making it async, I know response.redirect but you need to add application path